# Android MapView set zoom level dynamically

Tags: android, set, zooming, android-mapview

I have a question please,
How can I set zoom level which depend on by current speed?
For example when moving slow. zoom to near, when fast, zoom to far.

Here is my algorithm:

```
private int calculateZoomLevelBySpeed(float speed) {
    int zoomLevelMax = mapView.getMaxZoomLevel();
    // default
    int zoomLevel = (zoomLevelMax > 0) ? (int)zoomLevelMax / 2 : 4;

    if (speed > 0) {
        // 300km theoretically max / max zoom steps
        double step = 300 / zoomLevelMax;
        zoomLevel = (int) Math.round(speed / step);
        // reverse
        zoomLevel = zoomLevelMax - zoomLevel;
        zoomLevel = Math.min(zoomLevelMax,  zoomLevelMax);
        zoomLevel = Math.max(zoomLevelMax,  1);
    }
    return zoomLevel;
}
```

This does not work, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Laszlo, the code you have posted is to calculate zoom level or for setting zoom level ?

Comment: `zoomLevel = Math.min(zoomLevelMax,  zoomLevelMax);`?

Comment: maybe this was the problem, I will try with fixed code, 

zoomLevel = Math.min(zoomLevel,  zoomLevelMax);

Comment: I don't know why but it does not work.

Comment: @Laszlo: It's `dynamically`

Answer (score -1):

try this, I didn't really test it, but I hope it helps

```
private int calculateZoomLevelBySpeed(float speed) 
{
    //assuming this line returns the max zoom level on maps
    int zoomLevelMax = mapView.getMaxZoomLevel(); 
    // default
    int zoomLevel = (zoomLevelMax > 0) ? (int)zoomLevelMax / 2 : 4;

    if (speed > 0) {
        // 300km theoretically max / max zoom steps
        double step = (speed / 300) * zoomLevelMax;
    }
    return Math.Round(zoomLevel);
}
```

Comment: As I see, the zoomLevel not affected by step in this code, not make any operation with step which can modify the zoomLevel

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this :

```
private int calculateZoomLevelBySpeed(float speed) {
    int zoomLevelMax = mapView.getMaxZoomLevel();

    if (speed > 0) {
        // 300km theoretically max / max zoom steps
        double step = 300 / zoomLevelMax;
        zoomLevel = (int) Math.round(speed / step);
        // reverse
        zoomLevel = zoomLevelMax - zoomLevel;
    }
    return zoomLevel;
}
```